# How can I filter disambiguated names in dbpedia

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to use the following SPARQL query to find the Rhône department in France.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:label "Rhone"@en.
  ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Place.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), 'en'))
}
```

Here is the DBPEDIA resource: http://dbpedia.org/page/Rh%C3%B4ne_(department)

The problem is that it keeps finding the river Rhone, and not the department (or state). If I change the rdf:type to PopulatedPlace or Settlement then the search doesn't find anything.

Is it possible for me to use '*' or '?' characters to broaden the search string, such as:

> '* Rhone *'

as in:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:label "*Rhone*"@en.
  ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Settlement.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), 'en'))
}
```

Second, I presume it is ok to use multiple filters in one query, such as:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x rdfs:label "Rhone"@en.
  ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Place.
  ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace.
  ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Settlement.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  FILTER (LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), 'en'))
}
```

Comment: Related question by the same author: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404805/query-city-state-country-abstracts-in-english

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create a search string with wildcards - sort of. You can `FILTER` strings to match a *regular expression* with `FILTER (regex(?label, "Rhone"))` which matches strings with the string "Rhone" anywhere in the contents. This `FILTER` can make the query execution slower.

However, this won't return the resource you want, as the department's label is "Rhône".

The wildcard character for any character is `.` (the period). So if you're unsure of the spelling of "Rhône" and want it to appear anywhere in the label, you can use

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Place.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  ?x rdfs:label ?label.
  FILTER (regex(?label, "Rh.ne") && LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), 'en'))
}
```

It does take a very long time to complete this query, because of the regular expression. I just tried this query, and it timed out.

The third query is valid, but will only match resources that are `dbpedia-owl:Place`s and `dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace`s and `dbpedia-owl:Settlement`s (at the same time). Rhône is all three.
If you want `dbpedia-owl:Place` or `dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace` or `dbpedia-owl:Settlement`, use:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * WHERE {
  {
  ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Place.
  ?x rdfs:label ?label.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  FILTER (regex(?label, "Rhône") && LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), 'en'))
  } UNION {
  ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:Settlement.
  ?x rdfs:label ?label.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  FILTER (regex(?label, "Rhône") && LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), 'en'))
  } UNION {
  ?x rdf:type dbpedia-owl:PopulatedPlace.
  ?x rdfs:label ?label.
  ?x dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract.
  FILTER (regex(?label, "Rhône") && LANGMATCHES(LANG(?abstract), 'en'))
  }
}
```